# Creating a Youtube channel ios app

Tags: ios, youtube, backend, playlist, youtube-channels

So I want to make an app with my own custom menu, from where I can have access to my videos on youtube. I know how to link individual videos but I want to be able to update it with a back end or just by adding more videos to my youtube playlists and not have to fully patch my app to add more content. wondering how you all might suggest I go about doing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sample will help you understand how to upload your videos to YouTube, https://github.com/youtube/yt-direct-lite-iOS